# How can I display the record in a particular sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to display particualr records in the top in sequcence from a single colum table. The following are the sample query

```
create table empp(ename varchar(100))


insert into empp values('Name3')
insert into empp values('Name4')
insert into empp values('Name2')
insert into empp values('Name1')
```

As I would like to display in 'Name2' and 'Name3' in the 1st and 2nd row others may be in any sequence. I have tried the following query but didn't getting the desired result

```
 select * from empp where ename in ('Name2','Name3') 
 union 
 select * from empp
```

Expected O/P

Name2
Name3
Name1
Name4

Comment: what's your Question.

Comment: edited my question. please take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 Select * from empp
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN ename = 'Name2' THEN 0 
          WHEN ename='Name3' THEN 1 
          else 2
          END
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13035/6) Demo

Comment: Sql Fiddle is intersting tool. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE()` for custom reordering of record.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
ORDER BY    CASE WHEN ENAME = 'Name2' THEN 0
             WHEN ENAME = 'Name3' THEN 1
             ELSE 2
        END ASC
```

but if you don' mind the ordering of `name2` and `name3` as long as they are in the first place, then `IN` will suffice.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
ORDER BY    CASE WHEN ENAME IN ('Name2','Name3') 
             THEN 1
             ELSE 2
        END ASC
```

Comment: will this display all records including name2 and name 3 as first and sec record?

Comment: WHERE ! it should be ORDER BY, isn't it?

Comment: This is wrong. It couldn't executed which was giving the issue. @praveen answer was helped me

Comment: @RameshMuthiah because my first answer constains a typo. It should be `WHERE` instead of `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Oho. Right !!! Thank you for your solution. However, I checked other one as answer even though you response first

Comment: @RameshMuthiah No problem at all `:D`